# Upgrade with third-party modules

Tags: upgrading

I'm trying to migrate a Drupal 7 website to Drupal 8.
I have installed on the same server those two websites. Drupal8 version is empty.
On the Drupal 7 website, more than twenty contrib modules are installed, like LinkIt, PathAuto, Token... 
I downloaded with Composer the D8 version of those modules. I installed them without any configuration. 
I followed the upgrading process on my D8 website, but the process cannot see installed modules on D8 version and told me that LinkIt or PathAuto won't be upgraded.

How can I fix it? Is there a solution to migrate configuration datas for these modules?

Answer (score 0):

Pathauto has migrations for settings & patterns [built into the D8 module](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/pathauto/-/tree/8.x-1.x/migrations). Linkit doesn't have built-in support migrations.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It seems that a lot of modules does not have migrations. I tried to recover media fields created with module media, but Drupal indicated: 'Attempt to create a field field_photo that does not exist on entity type node.' Moreover, menus are not imported. Is that a normal behaviour?

Comment: Migrate support is based on whether each contrib module maintainer has decided to do the work or have someone else in the community supply a patch. Generally, the larger the install base, the more likely a pre-defined migration path will exist. Media in Drupal has been somewhat fractured until 8.6 where core now supports it so that might be the case here. There are core-defined D7 menu item migrations.